# modx revo ajax call don't execute snippet inside chunk

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have an ajax call. I want to get a chunk in this ajax call. In this chunk it contains a snippet.

My chunk looks like:

```
<div > this is the content [[!mySnippet]] </div>
```

It seems that it does not execute the snippet. `It returns this is the content [[!mySnippet]]` and not executed snippet.

I have tried `getChunk(), parseChunk()` seems not working.
I have many chunks so i do not want to create resources for each chunks. Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks,
Awlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling a custom endpoint in your ajax or is it a modx page? If its a custom endpoint like a php page, you need to include modx index.php and run it in API_MODE (See this page for description: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/loading-modx-externally).

After youve included modx you'll be able to do $modx->runSnippet('mySnippet'), but you'll have to modify the chunk since doing $modx->getChunk('yourChunk') won't execute any snippets inside it. If you want to use the same chunk, you could parse it yourself afterwards like this;

```
$snippetData = $modx->runSnippet('mySnippet');
$chunkHtml = $modx->getChunk('yourChunk');
$finalOutput = str_replace('[[!mySnippet]]', $snippetData, $chunkHtml);
```

Comment: I have added index.php and i have got global modx object. My initial approach was not to use runSnippet. But seems that I have to use runSnippet now.

Answer (score 4):

`str_replace('[[!mySnippet]]', $snippetData, $chunkHtml);` - will be a temporary solution, but if you in the future will need a full parsing of all modx tags and input/output filters i'll advice you to use this code:

```
// your chunk
$msg = "<div > this is the content [[!mySnippet:empty=`no data`]] </div>";

// Parse all MODX tags in results
$maxIterations = (integer) $modx->getOption('parser_max_iterations', null, 10);
$modx->getParser()->processElementTags('', $msg, false, false, '[[', ']]', array(), $maxIterations);
$modx->getParser()->processElementTags('', $msg, true, true, '[[', ']]', array(), $maxIterations);

// output result as example
print $msg;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will it execute the snippet inside `$msg` ?

Comment: Snippet is also a tag, so it will be processed as all other tags -  http://bobsguides.com/revolution-tags.html